# What 60s book had colour pictures of space ships dropping cotton-wool-like objects?

Tags: story-identification, books

My kids are 12 years old, and I remember reading a book when I was that age which seemed the best science fiction book ever. It was about 1968 but I think the book was a few years old.

It had gorgeous colour templates of strange  worlds in it. One scene had small cigar-shaped spaceships that dropped little cotton-wool-like objects. I think the author's name ended 'Clark'. Anyone know the name of the book?

Comment: There's not really enough information to provide an answer; can you provide more details about the story? If the author was indeed Arthur C. **Clarke**, you might want to take a look at [this Google Images search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1901&bih=1102&q=arthur+c.+clarke&oq=arthur+c.+&gs_l=img.3.0.0l10.2019.4337.0.8449.10.10.0.0.0.0.64.475.10.10.0....0...1.1.64.img..0.10.474.LR41OGE3rD0#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=arthur+c+clarke+books) for covers of books that might remind you of the story.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE rob! Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. You can also visit [How to ask a good question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) together with this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) and subsequently add more details to your question, so that it will be easier for others to find the book that you are searching for.

Answer (score 4):

[*Galactic Geographic*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1843400707) by Karl Kofoed

> One scene had small cigar shaped spaceships that dropped little cotton wool like objects

[image]

<sub>[Image source](http://70sscifiart.tumblr.com/post/159894497450/karl-kofoed)</sub>

Comment: Sometimes Imgur acts up for me as well, in which case I download the picture and then upload it from my computer ;)

Answer (score 2):

It might be one of the Venus Prime books, by Arthur C Clarke.  It was a series of six novels, each one an expanded version of an earlier Clarke short story.  Each one included templates of the technology in the story, especially spaceships.  Clarke co-wrote the novels with Paul Preuss.  The six novels are Breaking Strain, Maelstrom, Hide and Seek, The Medusa Encounter, The Diamond Moon, and The Shining Ones.  Any of them sound familiar?

Comment: Those seem like they'd be a bit too recent, having been published in 1989 and later.